# U-sql ocrextractor not working

Tags: u-sql

Trying to extract text information from a jpg file using Ocrextractor. Getting error connot implicity convert type Cognition.Vision.OcrExtractor to Microsoft.Analytics.Interfaces.IProcessor

Comment: Hi & welcome to SO. In order for us to be able to help you we need more information like the code that is generating the error and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

The Processor has been changed into an Extractor and a new Processor has been introduced. See here for details: https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Winter/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Winter.md#u-sql-cognitive-library-additions

Comment: Thanks Mike, this worked with the latest code. Any update on the limitations such as the file size 4 MB limitation?

Comment: getting an error while using ocrextractor "Unhandled exception from user code: "An item with the same key has already been added." Please give some direction on this.

Comment: This is a known bug that can occur at times. Can you send me more information in email ([usql] at microsoft dot com) so I can follow-up with the engineering team to get an ETA?